# Guess what I'm listening to

Tags: riddle, knowledge, music

```
I invite you to find the song I listened 
to my nerd eye, the title glistened.

The author if to find you crave, 
surely they are not a slave; 
footwear for a trip to cave, 
many things in that you save.

Trying to find the song's upsetting, 
'cause it's just a bunch of settings:

Remember the high times you were racing 
It's in my do's to be high but not to be dumb, or I'll lose my head 
Emma I love you 386 times 
Best is 30 
Give me a bunch of nothing, and then nothing
```

Okay, enough for now! I had to use internet help to make this list anyway.

Disclaimer: This is crazy. The way I chose to describe the song is actually a whole another album. Anyway, I'll count it correct either way.

Very slight tip:

> Finding the author(artist) is much easier than finding the song itself

Tip:

> The kind of knowledge needed is computers, old school stuff (around '80s-'90s I guess)

Strong tip:

> Each of the lines of the 2nd stanza except the first describe one word from the artist's name

Comment: If the answer is an actual song rather than something more abstract, I think this needs the knowledge tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The artist you're listening to is:

> **MASTER BOOT RECORD (MBR)**, a 'synth metal project with chiptune and classical influences' (according to [synthwave.fandom.com](https://synthwave.fandom.com/wiki/MASTER_BOOT_RECORD)). This artist has a reputation for concealing puzzles and secret messages in his work, making them an appropriate choice for this puzzle!

You can derive the name from the second stanza:

> *The author if to find you crave,*
>  *surely they are not a slave;* **= MASTER**
>  *footwear for a trip to cave*, **= BOOT**
>  *many things in that you save.* **= RECORD**

The lines in the fourth stanza provide clues towards specific songs by this artist:

> *Remember the high times you were racing*
>  [**DEVICE=HIMEM.SYS**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6yItsXGX984)
>  (reMEMber, 'hi'='high')
>
>  *It's in my do's to be high but not to be dumb, or I'll lose my head*
>  [**DOS=HIGH, UMB**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TY4TSB0A1HI)
>  ('do's', 'high', '(d)UMB' losing its head)
>
>  *Emma I love you 386 times*
>  [**DEVICE=EMM386.EXE**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDf3mqaWMSw)
>  ('Emm'='Emma', '386')
>
>  *Best is 30*
>  [**FILES=666**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wR4Plqtglds)
>  (Going over '30' in the FILES= statement [may decrease the computer's performance](https://www.computerhope.com/ac.htm) - 30 is found to work the best...)
>
>  *Give me a bunch of nothing, and then nothing*
>  [**DBLSPACE.EXE**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KuffB1ZbATY)
>  ('double space')

Four of these songs appear on the same EP by this artist:

> '**C:>EDIT CONFIG.SYS**' (the exception is DBLSPACE.EXE, which appears on '*Floppy Disk Overdrive*')

As a result, I suspect that the song you are listening to is (by word association):

> [**CONFIG.SYS**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RbHfqAa_uBk), currently the artist's most-played song on Spotify. This title would certainly 'glisten' to your 'nerd eye' (stanza 1), as this takes its name from the [primary configuration file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CONFIG.SYS) for the DOS operating system, and as a result could be described as '*just a bunch of settings*', as in stanza 3 of the puzzle.

Comment: You are correct, excellent! I love this music.